# how to make a sparse pandas DataFrame from a csv file

Tags: python, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I have a rather large (1.3 GB, unzipped) csv file, with 2 dense columns and 1.4 K sparse columns, about 1 M rows.

I need to make a pandas.DataFrame from it.

For small files I can simply do:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

For the large file I have now, I get a memory error, clearly due to the DataFrame size (tested by `sys.getsizeof(df)`

Based on this document:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html#migrating

it looks like I can make a DataFrame with mixed dense and sparse columns.

However, I can only see instructions to add individual sparse columns, not a chunk of them all together, from the csv file.

Reading the csv sparse columns one by one and adding them to df using:

```
for colname_i in names_of_sparse_columns:
    data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', usecols = [colname_i])
    df[colname_i] = pd.arrays.SparseArray(data.values.transpose()[0])
```

works, and `df` stays very small, as desired, but the execution time is absurdly long.

I tried of course:

```
pd.read_csv(path_to_input_csv, usecols = names_of_sparse_columns, dtype = "Sparse[float]")
```

but that generates this error:

```
NotImplementedError: Extension Array: <class 'pandas.core.arrays.sparse.array.SparseArray'> must implement _from_sequence_of_strings in order to be used in parser methods
```

> Any idea how I can do this more efficiently?

I checked several posts, but they all seem to be after something slightly different from this.

---

**EDIT** adding a small example, to clarify

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys

# Create an unpivoted sparse dataset
lengths = list(np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 5, size = 10000))
cols = []
for l in lengths:
    cols.extend(list(np.random.choice(100, size = l, replace = False)))
rows = np.repeat(np.arange(10000), lengths)
vals = np.repeat(1, sum(lengths))
df_unpivoted = pd.DataFrame({"row" : rows, "col" : cols, "val" : vals})

# Pivot and save to a csv file
df = df_unpivoted.pivot(index = "row", columns = "col", values = "val")
df.to_csv("sparse.csv", index = False)
```

This file occupies 1 MB on my PC.
Instead:

```
sys.getsizeof(df)
# 8080016
```

This looks like 8 MB to me.
So there is clearly a large increase in size when making a `pd.DataFrame` from a sparse csv file (in this case I made the file from the data frame, but it's the same as reading in the csv file using `pd.read_csv()`).

And this is my point: I *cannot* use `pd.read_csv()` to load the *whole* csv file into memory.
Here it's only 8 MB, that's no problem at all; with the actual 1.3 GB csv I referred to, it goes to such a huge size that it crashes our machine's memory.
I guess it's easy to try that, by replacing 10000 with 1000000 and 100 with 1500 in the above simulation.

If I do instead:

```
names_of_sparse_columns = df.columns.values

df_sparse = pd.DataFrame()

for colname_i in names_of_sparse_columns:
    data = pd.read_csv('sparse.csv', usecols = [colname_i])
    df_sparse[colname_i] = pd.arrays.SparseArray(data.values.transpose()[0])
```

The resulting object is much smaller:

```
sys.getsizeof(df_sparse)
# 416700
```

In fact even smaller than the file.

And this is my second point: doing this column-by-column addition of sparse columns is very slow.

> I was looking for advice on how to make `df_sparse` from a file like `"sparse.csv"` faster / more efficiently.

In fact, while I was writing this example, I noticed that:

```
sys.getsizeof(df_unpivoted)
# 399504
```

So maybe the solution could be to read the csv file line by line and unpivot it. The rest of the handling I need to do however would still require that I write out a pivoted csv, so back to square one.

---

**EDIT 2** more information

Just as well that I describe the rest of the handling I need to do, too.

When I can use a non-sparse data frame, there is an `ID` column in the file:

```
df["ID"] = list(np.random.choice(20, df.shape[0]))
```

I need to make a summary of how many data exist, per `ID`, per data column:

```
df.groupby("ID").count()
```

The unfortunate bit is that the sparse data frame does not support this.
I found a workaround, but it's very inefficient and slow.

> If anyone can advise on that aspect, too, it would be useful.

I would have guessed there would be a way to load the sparse part of the csv into some form of sparse array, and make a summary by `ID`.

Maybe I'm approaching this completely the wrong way, and that's why I am asking this large competent audience for advice.

Comment: When you say sparse columns, do you mean that they're mostly zeros in the CSV or that they're in the CSV in some weird indexed format?

Comment: Not even zero's. Just empty. Two consecutive comma's in the csv. I am posting an example. Just a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the faintest idea why someone would have made a CSV in that format. I would just read it in as chunks and fix the chunks.

```
# Read in chunks of data, melt it into an dataframe that makes sense
data = [c.melt(id_vars=dense_columns, var_name="Column_label", value_name="Thing").dropna() 
        for c in pd.read_csv('file.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=100000)]

# Concat the data together
data = pd.concat(data, axis=0)
```

Change the chunksize and the name of the value column as needed. You could also read in chunks and turn the chunks into a sparse dataframe if needed, but it seems that you'd be better off with a melted dataframe for what you want to do, IMO.

You can always chunk it again going the other way as well. Change the number of chunks as needed for your data.

```
with open('out_file.csv', mode='w') as out:

    for i, chunk in enumerate(np.array_split(df, 100)):

        chunk.iloc[:, 2:] = chunk.iloc[:, 2:].sparse.to_dense()
        chunk.to_csv(out, header=i==0)
```

Comment: Thanks; yes, in the meantime I did something similar. Indeed, I still needed to concat the sparse data columns into df, I had no alternative. On the other hand, for making the data summary, the unpivoted data are still the best, I think. Unfortunately I am having trouble with that, mostly with reshaping. I will make a new post regarding that.

Comment: I can't imagine a summary that you could do with your sparse wide dataframe that you can't do more efficiently with a long dataframe.

Comment: That's true. And I found a very good pandas function to do that, similar to R's xtabs. It only takes seconds. Very powerful. So yes, it looked like having to rewrite the code to address this memory issue was an inconvenience, but in fact it forced me to produce better, leaner, much less demanding scripts.

Comment: I had spoken too soon. Horrendous sting in the tail of using a pandas DataFrame with sparse columns: writing it out to csv (I agree, not a good format at all, but it is unfortunately needed for what we do next with the data) takes an eye-wateringly long time. 3+ h for 1.4 GB. Everything else is fine and very memory-efficient and fast. I feared there would be some catch :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65305121/pandas-sparse-data-export-to-csv-speed-explanation Not the first one to notice... and there is no answer.

Comment: That is perhaps another good reason to not write massive wide dataframes which are mostly sparse. It's pretty common that sparse data structures behave weird so it's worth getting comfortable with chunking them and turning them into a really common dense data structure if needed. (Edited the answer with a possible solution)

Comment: Thanks; I will try this as soon as I can. Just to be sure, this writes the file out by rows, right? In my example above this would work because the whole dataframe is sparse and is of the same data type. In my 'real world' case, the first 2 columns are dense strings, the columns that are appended at the end are dense integers. So maybe I should figure out a way to do this densification and writeout *by columns*, assuming it is even possible. I know, not making this easy at all; unfortunately the constraints come from other processes on which I have no control.

Comment: You can't write a file out by columns. That's not how files work. You'll need an extra step to only convert the sparse columns to dense in the chunk, but it should work fine. The pandas sparse data structures are weird, but most sparse stuff is.

Comment: Thanks again, it does indeed work, it's much faster! I will probably change the densification code to account for cases where the sparse columns are known by name rather than by position, and/or are not only the ones from the 3rd to the end.

Comment: And the modification works too. Now a new problem came up. I made a copy of the original input csv, to see if writing it out would give the exact same output as the input. Answer is no. The data are altered, e.g. 3.521 becomes 3.5210000000000004... I guess this is a more general python thing, maybe related to data types. And i guess using sparse columns did not matter in this respect. I might make a separate post for that.

Comment: Add the float_format argument to the `to_csv` call if you want to control float formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The same file.csv should not be read on every iteration; this line of code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', ...)
```

should be moved ahead of the for-loop.

To iterate through names_of_sparse_columns:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header = 0).copy()
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header = 0).copy()
for colname_i in names_of_sparse_columns:
    dataFromThisSparseColumn = data[colname_i]
    df[colname_i] = np.reshape(dataFromThisSparseColumn, -1)
```

Comment: And then `colname_i` would not be defined, would it?

Comment: I adjusted/finished the solution; I tested it in a basic example since I don't have your dataset, so if I understood that your goal is to iterate through the values in the dataframe names_of_sparse_columns from the data variable. However, based on your description I'm still not entirely sure what your end goal is; but I provided a solution to the coding issue specifically so hopefully it works. If not, provide more details or a more concise description of the problem and intended solution.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will add more information to clarify.